# Get paths of files containing decorated functions

Tags: python, path, python-decorators

I'm writing a Python decorator and I want to know the names of all the files that contain the decorator at runtime. The decorator might *not* be in the same module as the files that use it.

More specifically, I actually want the paths of these files, because I want to determine if there are uncommitted `git` changes to these files (assuming they are using `git`). Then I could use

`git -C <path> status` or `GitPython` vel sim.

I'm aware of `os.path.abspath` but using it would require somehow passing the filename, which doesn't seem feasible through a decorator.

Comment: You can write the decorator as a callable object class, and register each file that passed into the decorator.

Comment: At runtime of what?  Please post your code and what the expected output should be.

Comment: @James I want to make this part of a package so I make no assumptions about whether the client code is using regular `Python`, `PyPy` or `Jython` (which affects my ability to use modules like `inspect` though if there is no solution without it, I'll take it). The code is just a basic decorator `def decor(f):def wrapper():pass;return wrapper`, replacing the `pass` with some logic that I'm asking help with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pycollect](https://allrod5.github.io/pycollect) for that:

```py
from pycollect import PythonFileCollector

collector = PythonFileCollector()
files = []
for entry in collector.collect("../some/base/search/path"):
    with open(entry) as file:
        if "@my_decorator" in file.read():
            files.append(entry)
do_stuff(files)
```

It's OS independent and [`PythonFileCollector::collect`](https://allrod5.github.io/pycollect/reference/pycollect.html#pycollect.PythonFileCollector.collect) returns you a list of [os.DirEntry](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) which you can use as Path-like objects.

[pycollect is available at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pycollect/):

```sh
pip install pycollect
```

*Disclosure: I actively maintain this lib at [github.com/allrod5/pycollect](https://github.com/allrod5/pycollect).*